# What is the name of this plant with orange fruit clusters in india?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Location: South India.

Month: June

Season: Rainy Season.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is some species of *Duranta sp.*.

Comment: I didn't exhaustively check the species but if anongoodnurse's ID is right, *D. erecta* is toxic; its berries and leaves and it's only songbirds who are not affected by those (Source wiki).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to find out the name of this tree is to realize that the flowers (and therefore the fruit) are in the form of a *raceme*.

[image]

Googling ***India bright orange fruit raceme*** in *Images* quickly brings up your [specimen](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1386&bih=726&q=India+bright+orange+fruit+raceme&oq=India+bright+orange+fruit+raceme&gs_l=img.12...1018.1018.0.2858.2.2.0.0.0.0.74.74.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.img..1.0.0.0.pSYDz8mWuN8) among others.

[image]

The name of that image leads to [other sites](http://www.plantanswers.com/duranta.htm) discussing the plant.

[image]

> Duranta erecta
>   Scientific classification
>   Kingdom:    Plantae
>   (unranked):     Angiosperms
>   (unranked):     Eudicots
>   (unranked):     Asterids
>   Order:  Lamiales
>   Family:     Verbenaceae
>   Genus:  Duranta
>   Species:    D. erecta
>   Binomial name
>   Duranta erecta
>
> [**Duranta erecta**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duranta_erecta) is a species of flowering shrub in the verbena family Verbenaceae, native from Mexico to South America and the Caribbean. It is widely cultivated as an ornamental plant in tropical and subtropical gardens throughout the world, and has become naturalized in many places. It is considered an invasive species in Australia, China, South Africa and on several Pacific Islands. Common names include golden dewdrop, pigeon berry, and skyflower.